# Error message when clicking hyperlink in Excel file

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS 2012. In main report having hyperlink. When click this hyperlink in browser (IE 11 or Chrome), it open sub report correctly. But once i download the main report to Excel 2013 and click hyperlink, it can't open sub report.

I am getting following error message in Excel file.
Unable to open "http://...". Cannot download the information you requested.

In SSRS 2005, it is working fine.

How can i fix this issue in SSRS 2012?

Thanks,

Raja Shekhar Reddy

Answer (score 0):

if exactly the same link works in your browser, but doesn't when you call it from Excel try this:

1. open IE
2. press alt (if you don't see main menu on the top)
3. click on 'File'
4. untick 'Work Offline'

this helped me